# Can't write to a Handle

Tags: haskell, io, handle

I'm writing a chat server in Haskell. My executable has the following code:

```
data Client = Client {idx :: Int, hClient :: Handle} deriving (Show, Eq)

tellClient :: String -> Client -> IO ()
tellClient = flip $ hPutStrLn . hClient

askClient :: Client -> IO (String)
askClient = hGetLine . hClient
```

which I expect to be able to use to write and read from a file. I'm writing tests against this code with HSpec. I have the following function to build temporary `Client` objects (which relies on the "temporary") library:

```
withTempClient :: Int -> (Client -> IO a) -> IO a
withTempClient cIdx f = withTempFile "tests/generated" "clientFile.tmp" axn
  where axn _ handle = f $ Client cIdx handle
```

I'm using this to test the code above as follows:

```
main = hspec $  do
  describe "client IO" $ do
    it "can ask and tell" $ withTempClient 1 $ \c -> do
      tellClient "hello" c
      hFlush $ hClient c
      askClient c `shouldReturn` "hello"
```

But the test fails with the following error:

```
   uncaught exception: IOException of type EOF (test/generated
   /clientFile11587.tmp: hGetLine: end of file)
```

I thought that maybe I was doing something wrong in `withTempClient`, so I added the following test case:

```
it "opens a handle corectly" $ withTempClient 1 $ \(Client _ h) -> do
  hIsOpen h `shouldReturn` True
  hIsWritable h `shouldReturn` True
```

but that passed, so I'm not sure what the issue could be. What am I missing?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you write to a file, the OS keeps track of the position at which you are in said file. You get an `EOF` error because you're at the end of the file (it was empty to begin with and everything you have written is *before* the current position).

To fix that you need to use `hSeek` to reposition yourself at the beginning of the file like so:

```
hSeek (hClient c) AbsoluteSeek 0
```

For more details about seeking, cf. this bit of [real world haskell](http://book.realworldhaskell.org/read/io.html#io.files.seeking).